# Using Lwuit Virtual Keyboard, the first character entered will not check for constraint validation

Tags: java-me, lwuit, virtual-keyboard

Using Lwuit Version 1.5, Im having a problem using the **Virtual Keyboard**.
Given a TextField with a Numeric constraint.
**The first character entered will go directly to the Textfield despite the constraint given.**

I´ve found the sourceCode in `actionCommand` on `VirtualKeyboard.java` producing this issue;

```
case INSERT_CHAR:
            Button btn = currentButton;
            String text = btn.getText();
            if (inputField.getText().length() == 0) {
                inputField.setText(text);
                inputField.setCursorPosition(text.length());
            } else {
                inputField.insertChars(text);
            }
            break;
```

As seen above the first character will never go through `insertChars` and check for validity later.

Question is: I can't figure out why is this behavior implemented, Im afraid to break something I don't realize if I override that deleting the "if" part.

**Anyone knows what the reason could be?**

If anyone already have a Workarround for this issue please Id appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Its a known bug in LWUIT 1.5 that we fixed in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/), unfortunately no one is maintaining LWUIT anymore.

Your options are either to live with this issue, patch LWUIT, use `TextArea` (which is pretty different) or migrate to Codename One.